# How can I load the compressed files asynchronously in TYPO3?

Tags: asynchronous, compression, typo3

how can I load the compressed (minified) files asynchronously in TYPO3?

the normal way:

```
includeJSFooterlibs {
  jquery = fileadmin/JS/jquery.min.js
  jquery {
    async = 1
  }
}
```

then i compress all files. How can i load the Compressed-FILE in async Modus?

```
config {
    minifyJS = 1
    minifyCSS = 1
    compressJs = 1
    compressCss = 1
    concatenateJs = 1
    concatenateCss = 1
    concatenateJsAndCss = 1
}
```

i need a way, to load async the "compress" File.
TYPO3 generated a news File.

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK, you can't - you'd need to pre-compress the files (using grunt or gulp for example) and then include them using the way you did it, with compression by TYPO3 turned off.

Comment: @Jost: It should be an answer and not a comment. Then it can help for more people :)

Comment: @AndrásOttó I'm not 100% sure about it, so not an answer...

Comment: okay, thanks for the comment! I hope it works with TYPO3 :)

Comment: Am I the only one who doesn't even understand the question? What about loading a Javascript file isn't already asynchronous? Why would you compress a file thats already minified?

Comment: While it goes without saying that good questions yield better answers you should at least take 1 minute to re-read your question before submitting. It not only makes it easier for everyone to help you with your problem but it's also good etiquette. Your question is extremely badly worded. Please elaborate.

Comment: @j4k3, @sven: As clarification: Loading JS as asynchronous means including it with the `async` attribute set on the script tag. If it is set, the browser may defer executing the script, instead of waiting with the page rendering at the place the script was encountered. TYPO3 can set that attribute on the script tag, but it does not work if the script is postprocessed (e.g. concatenated with other scripts and gzip compressed). The question is: How do I set the `async` attribute for scripts postprocessed by TYPO3?

Comment: @Jost: I agree there is a good question there and a very useful answer to others, also. However the question as it is, is not very thoughtful. Maybe you want to edit the question into better wording to point out the problem more?

Comment: In your question, you are not very clear about compression and concatenation. You jquery.min.js seems to be compressed (or minified) already. I believe the OP mean concatenation.

Comment: i give u a better briefing!

Comment: Important hint: the "async" attribute only works at TYPO3 version 7.1.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, I am also quite sure you can't do that. Also if it worked, you wouldnt want to load all your js asynchronously. (That would be the case if your js is merged in one file).

However you can do this:

```
config {
  concatenateJs = 1
  concatenateCss = 1

  compressJs = 1
  compressCss = 1
}

includeJSFooterlibs {
  jquery = fileadmin/JS/jquery.min.js
  jquery {
    async = 1
    disableCompression = 1
  }
  file00 = fileadmin/JS/foo.js
  file01 = fileadmin/JS/bar.js
}
```

Use compression and concatenation for all your assets, then disable it selectively for your jquery include.

I hope this solution works for you.

Comment: thanks, but i need the async for the compressed files ;)

Comment: But jquery.min is compressed already? The use-case you describe does not make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: jep, but i need all in one file.

Comment: @SebastianSchmal Just for clearance: What you want is to load the *merged* (or *concatenated*) file asynchronously. It seems you just mixed that up.

Comment: jep! that i need ;)

Answer (score 1):

1. Concatenation, not compression is disabling the async.
2. Using async for scripts that are loaded in the footer probably doesn't make much sense. Using includeJSFooterlibs puts your scripts in the footer - bottom of the page (loaded after page is parsed and loaded). (see ["Efficiently load JavaScript with defer and async"](https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-async-defer/) and ["Async Attribute and Scripts At The Bottom"](https://css-tricks.com/async-attribute-scripts-bottom/))
3. Additionally, async **may change the order, so be careful with that** if you have several scripts to load.
4. If you are using TYPO3 9, you may also want to look at [defer](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/latest/Setup/Page/Index.html#includejs-array)
5. And last but not least: you are loading jquery from fileadmin, might want to check out possibility of creating a [sitepackage](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/SitePackageTutorial/) extension to maintain your layout stuff.

Also to clarify,

- concatenate : merge all source files into 1 file
- minify : remove irrelevant characers (e.g. whitespace). jquery.min is minified, not compressed
- compress : use some compression algorithm (e.g. GZIP)

The docs currently explain `config.compressCss` to mean minify **and** compress, but `compressJs` to mean only compress. I find that a little confusing, but if you compress a file, you basically get a minification as well.

To get back to your question:

```
config {
  compressJs
  concatenateJs
}
page.includeJsLibs {
  jquery = EXT:mysitepackage/Resources/Public/JavaScript/jquery.min.js
  jquery.async = 1
  jquery.excludeFromConcatenation = 1
}
```

If you do that for all your files, obviously you can just omit the `config.concatenateJs` in the first place. But as stated above, **it may not be what you want and make sure your scripts will get loaded in proper order**.

(I have omitted the CSS stuff here, to make it simpler.)

---

TYPO3 TypoScript Reference:

- [config](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/latest/Setup/Config/)
- [page.includeJS](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/latest/Setup/Page/Index.html#includejs-array)

---

Also, I would simplify the question by removing minifyJS, minifyCSS and concatenateJsAndCss.

- `concatenateJsAndCss` is [deprecated in TYPO3 9.4](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/9.4/Deprecation-65578-ConfigconcatenateJsAndCssAndConcatenateFiles.html)
- `minifyJS` and `minifyCSS` have been removed.

In any case, you do not need several options that do the same thing (concatenateJsAndCss **and** concatenateJs, concatenateCss).

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is load the compressed file in your template. Here is my DefaultTemplate.html extract of doing that for the compressed CSS file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/typo3temp/assets/compressed/merged-3f4572cd49b959626fc38730095acbb0-23be5be3f22e030757a0bb134c3718a5.css?1514538093" media="all">
```

As Google Pagespeed Insights would otherwise throw an error regarding the speed optimization. With this little manual trick I managed to get 98/99 on my Typo3 v8.7.9 projects:
https://lightningsoul.de
https://renoi.de
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flightningsoul.de%2F

Of course, doing this manually can be a bit of a hazzle when updating CSS / JS but it is the easiest way.
In your case the line would look something like this:

```
<script src="/typo3temp/assets/compressed/merged-ffdbb82fe741d3f165401ef485235b9f-995014bd04096b10820bbc2df443a90b.js?1514463856" async></script>
```

Hope this helps. Oh, and keep in mind that the file will not be updated when clearing the cache but you could easily attach a variable for that after the ? in case you need that.

And I would recommend using something like grunt to generate the file instead of Typo3. That way you do not have to manually switch the Typoscript, generate the new file and attach it to the template everytime you change it.